# Why my app crash without error using PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I program an app witgh QT interface to read modbus data, I display data on GUI create with PyQT5.
When I launch program, it crash after few second, I haven't message error. I used debugger and nothing wrong thing, program just close.

This is a part of my code where is my problem, I'll explain after

```
def displayModbus(self):

    modbusReturn = modbus.readModbus()
    commStatus = modbusReturn[0]


    if commStatus:
        listRegValue = modbusReturn[1]

        #Display data to ui

        if str(listRegValue[1]) == "1":  #HEATING_ST
            self.ui.lnHeatingStatus.setText("On")
        else:
            self.ui.lnHeatingStatus.setText("Off")

        # self.ui..setText(str(listRegValue[2])) #WAIT_TIME_CHG
        # self.ui..setText(str(listRegValue[3])) #RUN_TIME_CHG

        if str(listRegValue[4]) == "1": #ON_WAIT_TIME_P
            self.ui.ledWaitTime.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color:green;}")
        else:
            self.ui.ledWaitTime.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color:red;}")
        
        if str(listRegValue[5]) == "1":  #RUN_CYCLE
            self.ui.lnRunCycle.setText("On")
        else:
            self.ui.lnRunCycle.setText("Off")

        # self.ui..setText(str(listRegValue[6])) #LEVEL_RESET
        # self.ui..setText(str(listRegValue[7])) #CYL_MAN_CYCLE
        # self.ui..setText(str(listRegValue[8])) #CYL_EMPTY
        # self.ui..setText(str(listRegValue[9])) #CYL_EMPTY_END
        # self.ui..setText(str(listRegValue[10])) #NORASYSTEM_MANUAL
        # self.ui..setText(str(listRegValue[11])) #NORASYSTEM_ON
        # self.ui..setText(str(listRegValue[12])) #HEATING_ALLOW

        if str(listRegValue[13]) == "1":  #LOW_AIRFLOW
            self.ui.lnLowAirflow.setText("Low")
        else:
            self.ui.lnLowAirflow.setText("Normal")

        # self.ui..setText(str(listRegValue[15])) #HUM_ALLOW

        TC1 = listRegValue[16] / 100
        self.ui.lnTC1.setText(str(TC1)+" °C") #TC1

        TC2 = listRegValue[17] / 100
        self.ui.lnTC2.setText(str(TC2)+" °C") #TC2

        TC3 = listRegValue[18] / 100
        self.ui.lnTC3.setText(str(TC3)+" °C") #TC3

        TC4 = listRegValue[19] / 100
        self.ui.lnTC4.setText(str(TC4)+" °C") #TC4

        self.ui.lnH1.setText(str(listRegValue[20])+" %RH") #HUM1


        waitTime = str(listRegValue[22] / 3600)
        self.ui.lnWaitTime.setText(str(waitTime+" hr")) #WAIT_TIME_D

        runTime = str(listRegValue[23] / 60)
        self.ui.lnRunTime.setText(str(runTime+" min")) #RUN_TIME_D

        timeRemainM = str(int(listRegValue[24] / 60)) 
        timeRemainS = str(int(listRegValue[24] % 60))
        self.ui.lnTimeRemain.setText(str(timeRemainM + " min "+timeRemainS + " sec")) #TIME_REMAIN_D

        self.ui.lnLevel.setText(str(listRegValue[25])) #LEVEL_D

        self.statusBar().showMessage("Modbus communication OK")

    else:
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Error modbus communication")
```

The problem come from this function after many try and error method. If I delete it program doesn't crash BUT if I modify it by print function (example: print(str(listRegValue[4]))) all is good so my problem doesn't come from mGUI assignation odbus module.
my function displayModbus is refresh every 5 second (using QtThreading).
If I keep just one variable to display my app doesn't crash.

I have another app to read and record modbus data using same displayModbus function (without QT5 display) and I haven't problem

I have this problem on 2 computers and I try it on 5 computers (4x windows 10 and 1x Linux)

- Python 3.8.6
- PyQT==5.15.1
- PyQt5-sip==12.8.1

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: run my script from the console to get the error message

Comment: Which script? My code through console doesn't display any error

Comment: Is by any chance `displayModbus` called directly within the thread? If so, that's the problem: GUI elements can only be accessed directly from the main Qt thread, not from external threads. You need to use signals and slots to do so (in your case, make the thread emit a custom signal, and connect that signal to `displayModbus`. The fact that "sometimes" it works is just due to some specific conditions that allow the queueing to work properly even while accessing UI objects from the other thread, but those conditions are both unpredictable and unreliable.

Comment: Thank you very much! I change my thread strategy. I put my displayModbus function in my run and send result to my GUI function.